# Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I used to use Mysql making my php script and now I wanted to switch this script to Mysqli and Im in trouble with changing All Mysql codes into Mysqli.

How to solve this problem?
The function of setting names to UTF8 not working. It says :

> Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

What's the second Parameter I'm missing here?

Here is the class I'm using

```
class Database {
    private $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname;

    public function __construct($host,$user, $pass,$name){
        $this->dbhost = $host;
        $this->dbuser = $user;
        $this->dbpass = $pass;
        $this->name   = $dbname;
    }   

    public function Connect (){
        mysqli_connect ($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbname)
            OR die (mysqli_error());
    }


    public function SetNamesUTF8($unicode){
        mysqli_set_charset($unicode);
    }
}

$Database = new Database('localhost','root','root','schoolmanager');
$Database -> Connect(); 
$Database -> SetNamesUTF8('UTF8');
```

Answer (score -2):

The first parameter should be:

> A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()

According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

So, you need to store the return value from mysqli_connect, and use it there. The second parameter is the charset identifier string, as you have already used. You will need it a lot of times, because it identifies the open connection. This is how you could do it:

```
class Database {
    private $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $link;

    public function __construct($host,$user, $pass,$name){
        $this->dbhost = $host;
        $this->dbuser = $user;
        $this->dbpass = $pass;
        $this->name   = $dbname;
    }   

    public function Connect (){
        $this->link = mysqli_connect ($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbname)
            OR die (mysqli_error());
    }


    public function SetNamesUTF8($unicode){
        mysqli_set_charset($this->link, $unicode);
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to call Connect before you can call other methods. Consider adding error handling for that.

You could also consider switching to the object oriented API as suggested by the linked documentation page, I think it will make life easier for you.

Comment: Can you please give me an example using my current class?
This is the first time I tried to work with Mysqli.. So...

Answer (score -2):

It's expecting a link, according to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php...

> bool mysqli_set_charset ( mysqli $link , string $charset )

```
class Database {
    private $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $link;

    public function __construct($host,$user, $pass,$name){
        $this->dbhost = $host;
        $this->dbuser = $user;
        $this->dbpass = $pass;
        $this->name   = $dbname;
    }   

    public function Connect (){
        $link = mysqli_connect ($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbname)
            OR die (mysqli_error());
    }


    public function SetNamesUTF8($unicode){
        mysqli_set_charset($link, $unicode);
    }
}

$Database = new Database('localhost','root','root','schoolmanager');
$Database -> Connect(); 
$Database -> SetNamesUTF8('UTF8');
```